# Cordovalib project not getting built with Xcodebuild 6.1 command line

Tags: ios, cordova, xcodebuild, xcode6.1

I created a sample cordova ios project using Cordova create command. The project creation was successful and when I open the xcodeproj in Xcode and do a build, project builds fine. When I try to use the xcodebuild command line tool to build the same project, it fails with the below exception.

```
BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===        
Check dependencies 2014-10-29 16:48:34.568 xcodebuild[74489:5403] -[DTDKProvisioningProfile identitySigningCertificates]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae6cdcce10 
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception ** Exception: -[DTDKProvisioningProfile identitySigningCertificates]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae6cdcce10
```

Tried with both Cordova version : 2.9.1 and 3.6.3
Xcode version : 6.1
Mac OS X version : 10.9.5

Comment: Getting same error with my project (not Cordovalib). Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mrvincenzo . I tried removing Xcode completely and installed a fresh Xcode 6.1 version from app store. It started working after that. Earlier I  had multiple versions of sdk like 7.1, 8.0, 8.1 and now that I have 8.1 alone, I don't see this issue anymore.

Comment: I installed Xcode 6.1 from fresh and it started working. Thanks a lot. I really think you should answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing Xcode completely and installed a fresh Xcode 6.1 version from app store. It started working after that. Earlier I  had multiple versions of sdk like 7.1, 8.0, 8.1 and now that I have 8.1 alone, I don't see this issue anymore